# Regarding one query error

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00904

Here is my Requirement when I am using the below query I am getting the correct response but the problem is I want to select the distinct records so please help me how can I use distinct in the below query

```
SELECT LISTAGG(PAC.DESCRIPTION || ' = '|| ORL.ITEM_PACKAGE_COUNT , ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PAC.DESCRIPTION || ' = '|| ORL.ITEM_PACKAGE_COUNT)
FROM ORDER_RELEASE_LINE ORL , PACKAGED_ITEM PAC , SHIPMENT SH , ORDER_MOVEMENT OM 
WHERE ORL.PACKAGED_ITEM_GID = PAC.PACKAGED_ITEM_GID
AND OM.ORDER_RELEASE_GID = ORL.ORDER_RELEASE_GID
AND OM.SHIPMENT_GID = SH.SHIPMENT_GID
AND  SH.SHIPMENT_GID = 'ULA/SAO.5000072118'
```

Comment: (SELECT LISTAGG(PAC.DESCRIPTION || ' = '|| ORL.ITEM_PACKAGE_COUNT , ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PAC.DESCRIPTION || ' = '|| ORL.ITEM_PACKAGE_COUNT)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT PAC.DESCRIPTION FROM ORDER_RELEASE_LINE ORL , PACKAGED_ITEM PAC , SHIPMENT SH , ORDER_MOVEMENT OM 
WHERE ORL.PACKAGED_ITEM_GID = PAC.PACKAGED_ITEM_GID
AND OM.ORDER_RELEASE_GID = ORL.ORDER_RELEASE_GID
AND OM.SHIPMENT_GID = SH.SHIPMENT_GID
AND  SH.SHIPMENT_GID = 'ULA/SAO.5000072118') PAC)

Comment: Please add your query to the question (and format appropriately) rather than as a comment.

Comment: Sure I will do that..I am new to this so that's why I have put this as a comment

Comment: SELECT LISTAGG(PAC.DESCRIPTION || ' = '|| ORL.ITEM_PACKAGE_COUNT , ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PAC.DESCRIPTION || ' = '|| ORL.ITEM_PACKAGE_COUNT)
FROM ORDER_RELEASE_LINE ORL , PACKAGED_ITEM PAC , SHIPMENT SH , ORDER_MOVEMENT OM 
WHERE ORL.PACKAGED_ITEM_GID = PAC.PACKAGED_ITEM_GID
AND OM.ORDER_RELEASE_GID = ORL.ORDER_RELEASE_GID
AND OM.SHIPMENT_GID = SH.SHIPMENT_GID
AND  SH.SHIPMENT_GID = 'ULA/SAO.5000072118'

Comment: Could please anyone know how can I use distinct with Listagg in the above query which i mentioned in my question

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery returns `SELECT DISTINCT PAC.DESCRIPTION` but outer query uses aliases and values from inner query `LISTAGG(PAC.DESCRIPTION || ' = '|| ORL.ITEM_PACKAGE_COUNT , ',')` `ORL.ITEM_PACKAGE_COUNT` is not returned by subquery. Try:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(SUBQ.DESCRIPTION || ' = '|| SUBQ.ITEM_PACKAGE_COUNT , ',') 
          WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SUBQ.DESCRIPTION || ' = '|| SUBQ.ITEM_PACKAGE_COUNT) 
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT PAC.DESCRIPTION, ORL.ITEM_PACKAGE_COUNT
         FROM ORDER_RELEASE_LINE ORL , PACKAGED_ITEM PAC , SHIPMENT SH , ORDER_MOVEMENT OM 
         WHERE ORL.PACKAGED_ITEM_GID = PAC.PACKAGED_ITEM_GID 
           AND OM.ORDER_RELEASE_GID = ORL.ORDER_RELEASE_GID 
           AND OM.SHIPMENT_GID = SH.SHIPMENT_GID 
           AND SH.SHIPMENT_GID = 'ULA/SAO.5000072118') SUBQ
```

Generally it is wrong practice to use same alias `PAC` in inner query for a table and in outer query for result of joined data. Another wrong practice is using implicit joins instead of defining explicit `INNER JOIN ON`

Comment: Thanks for you response but the problem is PAC.Item_package_count will not be valid for me as there is no column named as (ITEM_PACKAGE_COUNT) is exist in the packaged_item table. so in the inner query I can take the select distinct PAC.DESCRIPTION, ORL.ITEM_PACKAGE_COUNT but the problem is I can only take the item_package_count from Order_release_line table. Please help

Comment: @otmnotifications But `PAC` in `LISTAGG` reference to whole subquery not to your single table `PACKAGE`. I've changed it to `SUBQ`

Comment: @otmnotifications If that query not works for you please edit your question and include there description of all tables used in query and describe what you need to obtain.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get distinct values from a query, and then build the `LISTAGG` of these distinct values, you can simply use `DISTINCT` in your query and wrap it with an external one where you use `LISTAGG`.

For example:

```
with dupValTab(s) as
(
    select 'something' from dual union all
    select 'something else' from dual union all
    select 'something' from dual
)
select listagg(s, ', ') within group (order by s)
from (
      select distinct s
      from dupValTab
     )
```